# docker installation of openproject: Phusion passenger fails to start after installation

Tags: passenger, phusion, openproject

I am trying to install openproject using docker on centos7.6 but Phusion passenger fails to start after installation. Error is suggesting it failed to parse response. 
`The preloader process sent an unparseable response:`. I don't know how to fix this issue.

stdout:

```
-----> Database setup finished.
       On first installation, the default admin credentials are login: admin, password: admin
-----> Launching supervisord...
2019-05-08 08:14:46,313 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2019-05-08 08:14:46,318 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2019-05-08 08:14:47,321 INFO spawned: 'postgres' with pid 155
2019-05-08 08:14:47,325 INFO spawned: 'apache2' with pid 156
2019-05-08 08:14:47,328 INFO spawned: 'web' with pid 157
2019-05-08 08:14:47,331 INFO spawned: 'worker' with pid 158
2019-05-08 08:14:47,351 INFO spawned: 'postfix' with pid 159
2019-05-08 08:14:47,360 INFO spawned: 'memcached' with pid 160
2019-05-08 08:14:47.634 UTC [172] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-05-08 08:14:44 UTC
2019-05-08 08:14:47,634 INFO success: postfix entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2019-05-08 08:14:47.649 UTC [172] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2019-05-08 08:14:47.653 UTC [155] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-05-08 08:14:47.663 UTC [177] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2019-05-08 08:14:48,670 INFO success: postgres entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-05-08 08:14:48,670 INFO success: apache2 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-05-08 08:14:48,670 INFO success: web entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-05-08 08:14:48,670 INFO success: worker entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-05-08 08:14:48,670 INFO success: memcached entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
2019-05-08 08:14:50,198 INFO exited: postfix (exit status 0; expected)
 --> Downloading a Phusion Passenger agent binary for your platform

 --> Installing Nginx 1.15.8 engine

--------------------------

 [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (app) and Ruby interpreter...
     (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
     Compilation successful. The logs are here:
     /tmp/passenger_native_support-15tsfhk.log
 [passenger_native_support.so] successfully loaded.
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /app/tmp/pids/passenger.8080.pid
Log file: /app/log/passenger.8080.log
Environment: production
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:8080/

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
Problems? Check https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/standalone/troubleshooting/
===============================================================================
[ N 2019-05-08 08:15:01.7338 404/Tb age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:519 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
Forcefully loading the application. Use :environment to avoid eager loading.
[auth_saml] Missing settings from '/app/config/plugins/auth_saml/settings.yml', skipping omniauth registration.
hook registered
App 439 output: [auth_saml] Missing settings from '/app/config/plugins/auth_saml/settings.yml', skipping omniauth registration.
App 439 output: hook registered
Creating scope :order_by_name. Overwriting existing method Sprint.order_by_name.
App 439 output: Creating scope :order_by_name. Overwriting existing method Sprint.order_by_name.
[Worker(host:d0b3748f627a pid:158)] Starting job worker
2019-05-08T08:15:45+0000: [Worker(host:d0b3748f627a pid:158)] Starting job worker
App 439 output: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:108:in `fork': Cannot allocate memory - fork(2) (Errno::ENOMEM)
App 439 output:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:108:in `handle_spawn_command'
App 439 output:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:78:in `accept_and_process_next_client'
App 439 output:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:167:in `run_main_loop'
App 439 output:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:207:in `<module:App>'
App 439 output:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
App 439 output:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
[ E 2019-05-08 08:15:46.6971 404/Tc age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /app: The preloader process sent an unparseable response: 
  Error ID: d7825364
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-wjSTKF.html

[ E 2019-05-08 08:15:46.7028 404/T8 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is d7825364. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[ W 2019-05-08 08:34:24.7967 404/Tk age/Cor/Spa/SmartSpawner.h:572 ]: An error occurred while spawning an application process: Cannot connect to Unix socket '/tmp/passenger.PKROzbY/apps.s/preloader.hyl9g8': No such file or directory (errno=2)
[ W 2019-05-08 08:34:24.7968 404/Tk age/Cor/Spa/SmartSpawner.h:574 ]: The application preloader seems to have crashed, restarting it and trying again...
App 543 output: [auth_saml] Missing settings from '/app/config/plugins/auth_saml/settings.yml', skipping omniauth registration.
App 543 output: hook registered
App 543 output: Creating scope :order_by_name. Overwriting existing method Sprint.order_by_name.
App 543 output: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:108:in `fork': Cannot allocate memory - fork(2) (Errno::ENOMEM)
App 543 output:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:108:in `handle_spawn_command'
App 543 output:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:78:in `accept_and_process_next_client'
App 543 output:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:167:in `run_main_loop'
App 543 output:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:207:in `<module:App>'
App 543 output:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
App 543 output:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
[ E 2019-05-08 08:34:52.2521 404/Tk age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /app: The preloader process sent an unparseable response: 
  Error ID: c2ce0823
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-bpsfAC.html

[ E 2019-05-08 08:34:52.2570 404/T8 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 1-2] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is c2ce0823. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import line in the log is this one:

> App 439 output: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:108:in `fork': Cannot allocate memory - fork(2) (Errno::ENOMEM)

This means your container is unable to allocate necessary memory. It could be that your system is in a OOM state and things are being killed or due to some other restriction on the daemon that prevents it from allocating additional memory

For reference:

https://success.docker.com/article/docker-daemon-error-cannot-allocate-memory

Comment: Yes, Problem was lack of memory. I was running on a system with 1GB RAM which was not enough. When I increased RAM to 2GB, the problem was resolved.